# Google Reader API PHP library

Tags: php, google-reader

Advise me Google Reader API PHP Library, please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a very simple one together for this tutorial.  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/building-a-mobile-web-application-with-the-google-reader-api/